# Can't connect to \\localhost\MyApp while publishing WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, localhost, clickonce, publish

*So as a few words description I have logic of the WPF app in my Console Application project with all classes and stuff. Then created database with entity framework. Then created WPF project to have visualised interface. And now I am at the point where:*

- locally everything works perfectly fine
- project compiled on other PCs also works good
- I want to publish WPF app to get installing setup
- again locally it works perfectly fine with the instalation and all
- **getting error when changing local names to "\localhost\MyApp\" directories**

**Error says:** "Can't connect to "\localhost\MyApp" because of an error. Can't create Web site "\localhost\MyApp". Path "\localhost\MyApp" doesn't exist or is unavailable. Provided path is not valid.

> Where: **localhost** in my understanding is reference to users' C:\
>   drive and **MyApp** is a folder created at this directory (was trying
>   many others but it doesn't change anything I guess).

So my question is basicaly how to fix that and if this is fault of my configuration or approach to the problem.

I'm pretty new to the c# and didn't really find such question with any answer. :(

Comment: WPF is not a web application, WPF is an executable. And what does it mean "logic of WPF app in my Console Application" ? Your question is confusing.

Comment: I have declared classes and connections between them for entity framework database  in one project and  then created wpf interface to operate around it. It doesn't matter.

I just want to publish it using UNC path and getting this error.

Comment: oK, I think your question is how to use/set up Click Once deployment. You might want to add a tag for that to your question.

Comment: yes indeed Im using this, this might be helpful, sorry for not specified question